# How can i remove the specific string with help of macro in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm analyzing sales report data. I need to remove some unnecessary string. This string will be generated from the POS. It's a default format.

This is the default format:

1. 1-99550 Alexander Keith #4924) on 27/12/2018   1:16:09PM for 0.00 hrs 0.00 min 56.00 sec
2. 1-99551 Mark Smith #4924) on 27/12/2018   1:16:09PM for 0.00 hrs 0.00 min 56.00 sec

I need to remove "**#4924) on 27/12/2018   1:16:09PM for 0.00 hrs 0.00 min 56.00 sec** " part of the string.

Comment: In case you're not sure about the number (it's not always going to be 4924), you might need "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Find `#*` (and Replace with 'nothing').

Answer (score 2):

Just use `LEFT()`/`SEARCH()`:

```
=LEFT(A1,SEARCH("#",A1)-1)
```

Returns

> 1-99550 Alexander Keith

Comment: Add a `Trim` to that if you don't want leading or trailing whitespaces